# How to make the error message of shiny::need depend on it's enclosed expression?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a Shiny app with a `fileInput` that takes in multiple files, but then I later validate the expected files were input (this is because there are too many to make a separate `fileInput` for each one). There's a corresponding `reactive` that performs the validation. Instead of listing all the required files when it fails to have them, I want only the missing ones listed. I created a quick sample app to show what I'm looking for

```
library(shiny)

fileList <- c("fileA.txt", "fileB.txt")

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Text Concatanation"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("theFiles", "Load files:", multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("textConcat")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  theText <- reactive({

    missingFiles <- fileList

    validate(
      need({
        # missingFiles <- setdiff(fileList, input$theFiles$name) # works but error message doesn't change
        missingFiles <<- setdiff(fileList, input$theFiles$name) # does not work and causes the test to fail
        length(missingFiles) == 0
      },
      paste("Missing required files:", paste(missingFiles, collapse = ",")))
    )

    x <- lapply(input$theFiles$datapath, readLines)
    names(x) <- input$theFiles$name
    x

  })

  output$textConcat <- renderText({

    print(x)
    x <- lapply(theText(), paste, collapse = "\n")
    x <- mapply(paste, names(x), x, sep = ":\n\n")
    x <- paste(x, collapse = "\n\n\n")
    x

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The magic is performed in the `reactive` `theText`. I want is to that if I load `fileA.txt` but not `fileB.txt` I'd get an error message like `Missing required files: fileB.txt`. I thought using the `<<-` assignment operator to escape the context of the expression inside `need` would do the trick but instead not only does it fail to modify `missingFiles`, the test also fails even when I load `fileA.txt` and `fileB.txt`. Is there a reason `<<-` is failing in this usage?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are trying to generating the missing file inside the first argument of function `need`. What I would suggest is to move this logic outside and keep `need` neat. Something like following:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Text Concatanation"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("theFiles", "Load files:", multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("textConcat")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  fileList <- c("fileA.txt", "fileB.txt") # files that are required

  # files that are currently missing
  missingFiles <- reactive({
    fileList[!fileList %in% input$theFiles$name]
  })

  output$textConcat <- renderPrint({
    validate(
      need(
        length(missingFiles()) == 0,
        paste0("Missing files: ", paste(missingFiles(), collapse = ", "))
      )
    )
    "nice, all files are uploaded"
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```